# AWK in Bash Script Fails with No Error On Text Insert

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to insert text to a .YAML file using a AWK in a bash script on MacOS. The script runs, no errors however; the text is not inserted to the file.

**target.yaml**

```
# some comment
alpha:
    charlie:
      - foo
```

**bash script**

```
#!/bin/bash

# Define the lines to be added
lines_to_add="    bravo:
      - bar"

# Specify the .yaml file path
yaml_file="../project/target.yaml"

# Use awk to insert the lines at line three of the .yaml file
awk -v lines="$lines_to_add" 'NR==3{print lines}1' "$yaml_file" > temp.yaml && mv temp.yaml "$yaml_file"
```

**The desired output:**

```
# some comment
alpha:
    bravo:
      - bar
    charlie:
      - foo
```

**Note:**
The awk command works correctly when inserting one string directly in the terminal;

```
awk -v lines="MY_NEW_LINE" 'NR==3{print lines}1' target.yaml > temp.yaml && mv temp.yaml target.yaml
```

Comment: If I run `awk -v lines="$lines_to_add" 'NR==3{print lines}1' target.yaml` I get the desired output

Comment: fwiw, your `awk` script works for me; what is the output from `awk --version`? consider enabling debug mode (`set -xv`; `set +xv` to disable) and remove the `> temp.yaml && mv temp.yaml "$yaml_file"`, then run the script ... perhaps there's something in the debug output that can shine a light on the issue; I'm guessing you've got an old version of `awk` (typical on MacOS) but not sure how that'd affect your script ...

Comment: @markp-fuso, awk version = 20200816. I'll set the debug and give another go.

Comment: Why not just `echo "$lines_to_add" >> target.yaml` ? what do you actually need awk for?

Comment: @Paolo - that's a good question and the only reason for awk was to insert the new strings, starting at a specific line. There is no requirement for that approach. Adding the strings at the end of the file is just as well.

Comment: Do you mean that after the script has completed, `temp.yaml` still exists and contains same data as the original file?

Comment: please use a [repro].

Comment: @FunnyChef : if possible, install either `mawk` (much faster) or `gawk` (unicode and misc bells&whistles). `macos` built-in `(n)awk` is flawed because not only it produces incorrect outcomes, it's even inconsistent when it comes to being incorrect ::: `nawk  'BEGIN { print (""~/\400/), (""~/[\400]/), (""~"\400"), (""~"\\400"),(""~/\0/), (""~/[\0]/), (""~"\0"), (""~"\\0")  }'` :::: they're identical to one another cuz byte octal codes wrap-around every `0400` (decimal 256). Any other `awk` correctly prints out all zeros (i.e. boolean FALSE). `nawk` prints out `0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1`.

Comment: The script you posted would do what you want using any awk as long as `../project/target.yaml` does actually exist and contain 3 or more lines so whatever the problem is, it's not in the code you've shared with us so far. Add `set -x` at the top of your script so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: Actually - one other thing that'd cause your script to fail would be if you didn't have permission to create `temp.yaml` in whatever directory you run the script from. Consider using `mktemp`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a yaml processor for this. Using [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) (version 4.2.0):

```bash
$ yq e -i '.alpha.bravo = ["bar"]' target.yaml
$ cat target.yaml
# some comment
alpha:
  charlie:
    - foo
  bravo:
    - bar
```

Comment: Thanks, Paolo, I was trying to keep this script as generic as possible since it's going to be used by multiple people and installing different tools isn't really an option for the use case.

Comment: @FunnyChef precisely because it's going to be used by multiple people you should use the best tool for the job. Do you really want people to have to modify a complex `awk` script to edit a yaml file?

Comment: I agree with your point, the right tool for the job is always preferred. There are however constraints with the project, that I have to operate within.

Answer (score 0):

I elected to use `echo "$lines_to_add" >> target.yaml` and drop the use of AWK since AWK was not a hard requirement for this effort.

Comment: You should really pursue debugging your original problem because whatever the problem is, whether it's something in your environment or something about the way you're coding or something else, will probably come back to bite you again in some future situation and it may not be as obvious and easy to debug at that time.